# Some mystic with 'extern' pointer to struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, extern

I have the following pieces of code with 3 global pointers to structs:

**structs.h:**

```
#pragma once

typedef struct Bignum {
  int digit;
  struct Bignum *next;
  struct Bignum *prev;
} Bignum;

typedef struct Stack {
  struct Bignum *head;
  struct Bignum *tail;
  char sign;
  struct Stack *next;
} Stack;

Bignum *num_tail;
Bignum *num_head;
Stack *stack_head;
```

**globals.c:**

```
#include "structs.h"

Bignum *num_tail;
Bignum *num_head;
Stack *stack_head;
```

When I compile these with other *.c* files (where I include *structs.h* and work with *num_tail*, *num_head* and *stack_head*), compilers (both *clang version 3.8.0* and *gcc 5.4.0*) compile this code without errors and program works as it should. But, as far as I'm concerned, this code **should not** be normally compiled and work because of lack of `extern` modifier in *structs.h*. Why does it work? :)

**UPD:** Yes, the answer is **tentative definitions**. Really, after initializing pointers to `NULL`, compilers give an error message. Thanks for all the replies!

Comment: Look up "tentative definition C"

Comment: Try to include the header into 2 different `.c` files and see what happen....

Comment: Here is a [link](https://github.com/Alkaizyr/Polish-calculator) to repository with this program. Header is included in all .c files and everything works fine.

Comment: @LPs Nothing, because `gcc` would put the variables of both files into a common section (FORTRAN-style).

Comment: @a3f Probably I'm wrong, but compiler should complain about multiple definitions. Shouldn't it?

Comment: LPs Normally yes, but `gcc` has an extension whereby across all translation units, uninitialized external linkage variables are combined (as-if all definitions had an `extern` in front, except one).

Comment: @a3f After a coffee I'm awake: Yes, you right. The keyword is **uninitialized** ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tentative definitions. You don't assign a value to those globals so they're treated as tentative definitions. The right-hand side `={0};` is assumed but only tentatively. If there's no real definition, the tentative definitions will get merged. If there is one, it'll win over the tentative ones without creating a linker conflict. This is normally implemented via common symbols (marked `C` in `nm` output), which means you can have tentative definitions for the same symbol even in multiple translation units. (I think it's best to not rely on this feature and stick to extern declarations coupled with nontentative definitions.)

Answer (score 1):

By the default there is no need for `extern` because non-static variables already have external scope.

In fact the declarations in `globals.c` are redundant.

```
Bignum *num_tail;
Bignum *num_head;
Stack *stack_head;
```

The compiler would give errors only for the case of redefinition, for example if `num_tail` in header and source are **both initialised**.